# ImageMagick: resize the image without scaling it

Tags: graphics, imagemagick

I have an image `example.png`, which is 50x50 pixels, mostly transparent and some black shape. What I want to achieve with imagemagick is, create a new image, `example_output.png`, which would be 100x100 pixels with transparent background and original 50x50 image in the center. Is this doable? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [extent](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent) operation:

```
convert example.png -gravity center -background none -extent 200%x example_output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 100x100 transparent image already, you can do this:

```
convert 100x100.png 50x50.png -geometry +25+25 -composite x.png
```

Otherwise, create the 100x100 first, then add the original:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:none 100x100.png
convert 100x100.png 50x50.png -geometry +25+25 -composite x.png
```